# Add new column in existing table starting from 0001

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have an existing table in sql what i need is a column which should have values start from 0001 and gets increments therefore for the values which are already present.
Table name account_details

```
Account_num   name    new_column
1            vicky      0001
2            Sam       0002
5           James    0003
8           Abdul      0004
```

Your help is mostly appreciated, 
I am using ms sql server.
Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to happen when the number of rows reaches 10000? Or will that be a problem someone else needs to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*,
       right(concat('0000', row_number() over (order by account_num)), 4) as new_col
from table t;
```

For existing column you can alter table schema :

```
alter table t
     add new_col as right(concat('0000', account_num), 4);
```

You can also create a view :

```
create view v1
   as select t.*,
             right(concat('0000', account_num), 4) as new_col
      from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not storing this derived information. Instead, you can use a view and `row_number()`:

```
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(order by account_num) rn
from mytable t
```

This saves you the effort of keeping the column up to date when new rows are added or deleted. Same functionality can be managed with a computed column.

The `0` padding can be managed with `format()` (which turns the number to a string):

```
create view myview as
select t.*, format(row_number() over(order by account_num), '0000') rn
from mytable t
```

That said, if you *do* want an actual column then you can use an updatable cte:

```
alter table mytable add rn varchar(4);
with cte as (
    select rn, format(row_number() over(order by account_num), '0000') new_rn
    from mytable
)
update cte set rn = new_rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that, according to your data, this is just `Account_num` increased to have 4 digits, a computed column would seem easiest:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD New_Column AS RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',Account_num),4);
```

---

OP has changed their data, invalidating my previous answer. The others are correct for what is now asked. Leaving here anyway.